Sum of self-adjoint operators
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. I am very well aware of the fact that the sum of two (possibly unbounded) self-adjoint operators is in general not self-adjoint, in fact not even densely-defined in general.
However, lets say $A:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{H}$ is a closed, densely-defined operator and I know that $A+A^{\ast}$ has a dense domain. Is it then true that $A+A^{\ast}$ is self-adjoint, or do I need more requirements in general?

Only vaguely related, but of potential interest to people who stumble across this question in the future: the hypothesis here that $A + A^$ has dense domain is a significant hypothesis, as for general closed and densely defined $A$ it is quite possible for the domain of $A + A^$ to be as small as ${0}$.  See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4282054/example-for-trivial-intersection-of-domains and examples cited there. (For what it's worth, I do not know if, or how, the hypothesis that $A + A^*$ has dense domain can be expressed any more "simply," as a property of $A$ "alone.")

The operator $A+A^\ast$ is not necessarily self-adjoint. Take any closed densely defined symmetric operator $A$ that is not self-adjoint (examples can be found here). Since $A$ is symmetric, we have $A\subset A^\ast$. By definition, the domain of $A+A^\ast$ is the intersection of the domains of $A$ and $A^\ast$, which is in this case the same as the domain of $A$. Moreover, $A^\ast$ coincides with $A$ on the domain of $A$. Thus $A+A^\ast=2A$, which is not self-adjoint by assumption.
